# Using TypeScript Index Signatures, can I specify another interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `Config` that will contain objects that I have not declared yet. I want these objects to each be an interface called `Environment`

Like so:
`Types.ts`

```js
interface Environment {
    root: string,
    dependencies: Object,
    devDependencies: Object
}

export interface Config {
    current: string,
    [index: string]: Environment,
}

// Object will look like this. However, when 
// I first initialize this the properties base and test will not exist yet.
const config: Config = {
   current: 'base',
   base: {
    root: 'path/to/root',
    dependencies: {},
    devDependencies: {}
   },
   test: {
    root: 'path/to/root',
    dependencies: {},
    devDependencies: {}
   },
   // can add additional Environments later on
}
```

I am getting an error when I run this called `Property 'current' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'Environment'.` I am unsure why this error shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `current: string` is interfere with `[index:string] Environment`**

Change to this would help:

```
export interface Config {
    [index: string]: Environment | string,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgG7CgexAWwnGQG8AoZS5XHMALmQGcwpQBzAGgqoBMIAHInxAJgERgwDyAIwBWEBGC5VkfDABEBQoqPFS5CsGQC+ZMhAAe-HFDDJQkWIhQBhPDGBtS3SgG1QfBYMzKwgbAC6DOhYuAREdgA+TCzsXKZkAPQZyDLyisgA7sAANsXIxTg4ANblwFUoYAAWwIwAdMgAEjgFEBjQHIWNRMiZ2QCSyB5QzPYgwGDAcMXAAF4NzYzITSj8uIK2YpvScIwocCA8W+J2RaXIILTIli12AJ4QYK1kCHgzPyAeNgMNwAzzIAC83ioCAArlAoPEGAByY6nJHKSioiAMcgqGj0ZBI-hwJoZMA4DL49E+VRaC46Q444wYyhqTSCekiRmkUxUZk+SDMHE0-HI4mk8mUypgakqPgc4S6CQ8lm0jR0xXcki8yj8qhZZAIc7IOA8S6mnjzYB4JZoTDYPCEcCbYok6DIPAmIA)

**Or to specify all your possible keys:**

```
interface Environment {
  root: string,
  dependencies: Object,
  devDependencies: Object
}

type Config = {
  [key in 'current' | 'base' | 'test']: Environment | string
};

const config: Config = {
  current: 'base',
  base: {
    root: 'path/to/root',
    dependencies: {},
    devDependencies: {},
  },
  test: {
    root: 'path/to/root',
    dependencies: {},
    devDependencies: {},
  },
};

config.current
```

By doing so, you will get no error referring to these types.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I think this could have worked potentially, but I do need access to both the `current` property and keeping the `Environment` interface. If I use `[index: string]: Environment | string` I end up getting an error in my file. I instead decided to use `current: any` and this seems to be working enough for me. I will mark this as the answer since it did answer my question roughly.

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer, you can specify your types.